# Disposable per-request lifetime with ServiceStack and NinjectContainerAdapter

Tags: ninject, servicestack

When using Ninject with ServiceStack, how would I specify that an object's lifetime is to be per-request, calling any IDisposable.Dispose method if necessary?

Per the docs, the default way of doing this is:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyType,IMyType>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
```

However, I have to use the `NinjectContainerAdapter` for my project. Normally I'd install `Ninject.Web.Common` and write:

`kernel.Bind<IMyType>().To<MyType>().InRequestScope()`

and my instance would be disposed of at the end of the request. How would I go about doing this in ServiceStack, say in a self-hosted scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to implement an `INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin` for ServiceStack. In the method `object GetRequestScope(IContext context);` you must return some object that has the lifetime of a request (an equivalent to `HttpContext.Current`))

Probably you could add an object to `HostContext` and return that one as scope. Best you make that object implement `INotifyWhenDisposed` and dispose it at the end of the request so that the objects are released imediately after the request instead of waiting for the object to be garbage collected..

Comment: Interesting. I will give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: After looking into this, isn't `INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin` from Ninject.Web.Common? That would pull in a reference to System.Web, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @BryanJ.Ross Overriding the `IAppHost.OnEndRequest()` hook may help here, it gives you a custom hook where you can add End of Request Dispose logic.

Comment: @mythz I ended up going that route. Now I just need to track which items were registered in RequestScope, and call `HostContext.Instance.TrackDisposable` on them.

Comment: I've abandoned this track. I'm now using the built-in Funq container, and things are much smoother.